# Changing icons when collapse is active (bootstrap accordion)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    <img class="icons" src="img/photography.png">
                    <img class="unactive" src="img/arrow.png">
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                  <div class="panel-body collapse-text">text.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And I want to change my icon which is class `unactive` to tranform: rotate 180deg when collapse is 'active'? Is it possible to do this using only CSS?

PS. I found many similar topics but I really haven't found any useful informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap adds a `collapsed` class when the accordion is closed. Use that to rotate the icon in your CSS..

```
.panel-heading .unactive {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);    
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);        
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);          
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);         
    transform: rotate(180deg);             
}

.panel-heading .collapsed .unactive {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);     
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);        
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);          
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);   
    transform: rotate(0deg);       
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/7vCbLaj4LX

Answer (score 0):

change rotate property with class

```
.panel-title .unactive{
 tranform: rotate 180deg
}
.panel-title .active{
 tranform: rotate 0deg
}
```